# Determine cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{f \in \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}} , \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ (0 \le f(n) < \frac{2015}{n+1})  \}$

$B = \{f \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} , \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ (f(2n) \neq f(2n+1))  \}$

My intuition is that both have cardinality continuum. Both setes are included in $ \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ so both are $\le C$ (where $C$ is continuum) and from cantor -bernstein theorem we want to show they are $\ge C$ so we can find a subset of $C$ included it $A,B$

I have idea in $B$ to take $f(2n)$ arbitrary values from $\{0,1\}$ and $f(2n+1)=1-f(2n)$ and such functions are $C$ since  so it will end $B$. Is it correnct ? how about $A$ ?

Comment: There is a bijection between $B$ and the set of subsets of odd numbers, so $B$ should be of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.
$A$ looks quite big, but I am not sure how to prove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. For $A$ you could try finding a bijection between

$$\left\{f\in\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}:\forall n\in\Bbb N\left(f(n)\in\left\{0,\frac{2015}{2(n+1)}\right\}\right)\right\}$$

and $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$. Your idea for $B$ works, though it could be stated more precisely: given $f\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, let $\hat f\in B$ be defined by

$$\hat f(n)=\begin{cases}
f\left(\frac{n}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
1-f(n),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: To $A$ my idea is we first pick $\frac{2015}{2(n+1)}$ and since rational numbers are dense then we can decide if we want pick number from interval $[0,\frac{2015}{2(n+1)})$ or $(\frac{2015}{2(n+1)}, \frac{2015}{n+1})$ so we can identify $ \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ if we want pick the first interval then $0$ or the second then $1$ and we will continue the algorithm. Is it good direction ?

Comment: @Mario: That works, but you’re making it too hard. You don’t have to do any arbitrary picking. If $g\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, define $\hat g\in A$ by $\hat g(n)=0$ if $g(n)=0$ and $\hat g(n)=\frac{2015}{2(n+1)}$ if $n=1$.

Comment: Ok but how is constructed $g(n)$ when it takes $0$ and when $1$ ?

Comment: @Mario: $g$ can be *any* function from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$; the point is that the map $g\mapsto\hat g$ is an injection from $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ to $A$, showing that $|A|\ge\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: shoudn't be in the end of your former coment "if $g(n)=1$" ? or that's correct ?

Comment: @Mario: Oops! Yes, it should: ‘$n=1$’ is a typo.

Comment: I have one more question: why it's injection? say $g(1)=g(2)=0$ then we have $\hat g (1)= \hat g(2)=0$ and $1 \neq 2$

Comment: @Mario: The injection is the map from $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ to $A$ that sends a function $g$ (which is an infinite sequence of zeroes and ones) to $\hat g$ (which is an infinite sequence of rational numbers); it’s an injection because if $f,g\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, and $f\ne g$, then $\hat f\ne\hat g$. If $f\ne g$, there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)\ne g(n)$, and the construction guarantees that $\hat f(n)\ne\hat g(n)$ and hence that $\hat f\ne\hat g$.